# High Level Language on an STM32

Tags: stm32, python

Are languages like [eLua](http://wiki.eluaproject.net/FrontPage) and [Micro Python](http://micropython.org/) feasible for production level use on an embedded micro like an STM32?

There doesn't seem too be much information outside of their sites. Not looking to do real time stuff in these languages directly, but perhaps linking them into existing lower level C modules could speed up testing and application level development. So I was curious if anyone has had much experience with these in the real world.

Comment: What is your definition of 'feasible'? IMO the problem with such languages is that for anything larger than a very small program the development cycle is much more tedious than for a convenstional cross-compiled language (Asm, C, C++, Pascal, Ada, ...) because most errors are only apparent at 'run' time.

Comment: The trade offs of compiled vs non-compiled languages are a little out of the scope of this question... But I don't believe having runtime testing or unit tests in place has to negate the trade off of faster development and prototyping that is possible with these languages.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding me at two points. In the cases I have used or read about (like picaxes, lua on the esp8266, micro-python) the edit-run cycle of these interpreted languages on such chips is more cumbersome than of compiled languages (the opposite is true on a PC). And the benefit of compiled languages (especially strong typed ones) is that more errors are caught early on, which wheights heavier when the development cycle is already cumbersome. Don't get me wrong: on the PC I use Python almost exclusively, but I don't see it use on a micro-controller.

Answer (score 2):

Ada is certainly feasible. See these articles for example:

http://www.embeddedrelated.com/showarticle/617.php
http://electronicdesign.com/blog/running-ada-2012-cortex-m4

Some resources [discussed here](https://www.adaformicrocontrollers.com/) and [available on github](https://github.com/rowsail/AdaForMicrocontrollers) including the Ravenscar (real-time tasking designed with reliability in mind) RTS.